# How to copy newly created CRM contact record to SQL table

Tags: sql, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, synchronization

I have written a plugin that fires off when new record is created (post). This plugin simple runs a SSIS package that moves newly created record details in to SQL table. I'm having to deploy this plugin as none isolation mode.

What I want to know is that is there any better solution to live sync CRM records with SQL table?

I am working on CRM 2011 RU 18 On premise.

```
                    string connectionString = "User Id=username; Password=password; Initial Catalog=db; Data Source=myServer;";
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO testPerson (Firstname, Lastname, Emailaddress, CrmGuid) VALUES (@FN, @LN, @Email, @CrmGuid)");
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = connection;

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", "James");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", "Bolton");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", "1152@now.com");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrmGuid", "C45843ED-45BC-E411-9450-00155D1467C5");

                        connection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    //////// Direct DB Connection ////////////     <--- END 1
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tracingService.Trace("CRM to mWeb Sync Plugin: {0}", ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
```

Comment: Firing up an SSIS package each time a record is created is overkill and will either need to be Async unless the end-user is expected to wait. I've seen SSIS packages take a minute or more to start-up.

Comment: @Nicknow it is Async and given it is a single record, it will take less then a minutes.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wasn't saying the insert would take a minute - I was saying that the SISS package startup (which is independent of the work being done) can take a minute or more. This is one of the reasons that having to start an SSIS package for each operation can be a problematic architecture.

Comment: @Nicknow I agree, I have given up on the SSIS idea and now trying to follow up your link regarding web service. (something I have never done before so might be worth learning too!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run this in sandbox mode you will not be able to directly target SQL (or run an SSIS package.)

The correct solution would be to target a web service.

Create a standard .NET web service (WebApi, ASP.NET old school, WCF, etc. - pick your poison) to which you can post the fields. That web service should take the fields are write them to SQL. This is basic .NET - you can use a `SqlCommand`, EntityFramework, etc. Deploy this web service to IIS as you would any web service.

You can get a full tutorial on creating an ASP.NET WebApi Web Service here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659131/Understanding-and-Implementing-ASPNET-WebAPI

Now, your plugin should call the web service you have created using `HttpClient`. So long as you have a FQDN (i.e., service.mydomain.com and not something such as localhost or 34.22.643.23) you will be able to run your plugin in sandbox mode (i.e., not isolation.)

You can secure your service using any IIS security feature or implement authorization in your WebAPI code.

Comment: thank you for the detail, I am giving this a go today. Will let you know how it all goes.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible alternative I see that plugin can use ADO Connection/Command e.t.c. to push data directly to external DB.

Comment: Will this work with plugin have to complete process within 2 minutes.

Comment: You can try but definitely that for such long-running process you should use Async Plugin. Just curious - why insert (as far as I understood) of a record to a table could take 2 mins?

Comment: the back office tables have contact records in three different tables so in one trigger I will take records from CRM and distribute them across three different SQL tables. I will also have to get the ID (PK) as I insert new records so I can build relationship between them. Hence I am bit worried that it might take longer then 2 minutes.

Comment: How could that be that insert of data even in 3 tables could take 2 mins? Do you insert only 1 contact or you insert/update all the existing contacts from CRM?

Comment: Since I have never written code to connect to SQL db, I following tutorial online and got it working in Windows form app. However, using same try catch block in plugin gives me weird error. 
My connection string is string connectionString = "User Id=admin; Password=myPass; Initial Catalog=myDatabase; Data Source=myServer; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Error message I get said fail to login: domain\myServer. 

for some reason the server name is taken as a username!

Comment: If you are passing a User and Password in the connection string then you shouldn't have `Trusted_Connection=Yes`.

Comment: @Nicknow I removed that string and re-run the code but it throws, Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission on the line where connection.Open(). I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: Does the user being passed in the connection string have the necessary SQL permissions? I would recommend creating a new question, specific to SQL without the CRM tags, to get a better answer as your question is no longer a CRM relevant/specific question but a general C#/SQL question.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Nicknow I finally learned(enough) and created my first WCF service and deployed it on the IIS. Yes, it was bit of work and learning but it works perfectly. From record creation to plugin completing to new rows created in my backend database, all within 2 minutes.

If anyone else in the same boat as me, I would suggest buying [This book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-WCF-A-Hands-Guide/dp/0596101627) as it was massive help to me.

Thank you guys once again for pointing me in the right direction.